# Combination tag wiki pages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-wiki

I love the tag wiki feature, but I just realised there could be a use case for combinations of tags. For example, the all too common question type "Give me regular expression to parse html?" It would be useful to have a defacto response on the [regex+html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+html) page.

Comment: The people posting the questions probably won't read the wiki, but it *would* be a good place to keep links to canonical answers so people closing dupes can find them easily.

Comment: @bemace That was my thinking as well.

Answer (score 2):

To me this sound like one big, huge can of worms for little benefit.

Firstly, it would require a massive re-architecture of the way we store tag wikis.

Next up, how would people find these wikis? We will be creating little bits of content in areas where potentially nobody looks.

Sorry, declining.

Answer (score 0):

I just put usage guidelines in the Tag Wiki, like so:

> The Excel tag is used for referencing
>   the Excel spreadsheet application from
>   Microsoft. If your question is about
>   VBA then also tag it VBA. If it is
>   about an Excel formula or worksheet
>   function, then tag it
>   worksheet-function.

The only problem is that the Team refuses to allow functionality to make the tags stand out, so they're easily missed.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. That's for the general excel tag. But say for example you wanted to add text that only makes sense when both excel and formula tags were in the question? You cannot create a tag wiki for the [combination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+formula). In other words, it's not to direct people about tagging but rather giving faq-like advice.

Comment: @marcog: he's saying you *could* put that in either/both of the wikis for those tags... But it doesn't matter, because the folks who post those questions won't dig to find the wiki anyway.

Comment: @Shog But you can direct them to it. Since tag wiki's don't allow for anchor references, it's better having a small, limited body of text to reference rather than a general blurb.

Comment: @marcog: if you want to *link to something specific*, then you might as well cut out the middleman and just link to the bobince answer like everyone else.

Comment: @Shog9, I agree, most people will never look at the Tag Wikis.