# Should we have FAQ style questions for tag related terms coined by the community that are commonly used across SE sites?

Tags: discussion, tags, terminology

I have being participating and reading discussions about tags. On some of these discussions the OP included a tag term that looks easy to understand like "hyphenated tag" (a tag having an hyphen) but sometimes the same term is used to refer to a "new meaning" like *a `hyphenated` tag is a tag made of multiple "tags" separated by hyphens* but there are other questions that use a different term for the same meaning like "composite tag".

Rather than discussing this particular case I would like your help about how to proceed when *a new meaning arises* for a term that has an accepted meaning between SE tag experts but might not be so obvios for others.

I.E. here we have [What is a blocked tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/289691) (now about "blocked tag" but originally was about "blacklisted tag". Either of these terms is included in [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/289691).

---

Some discussions on this site about tag terms

Not so commonly used (ordered by Q id)

- Sub-tag ->        [Should questions be tagged with both a tag and a "sub-tag"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41206/289691)
- Root tag ->       ["Root" tags to organize larger sites with multiple categories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87656/289691)
- Compound tag ->

  - [How can we address compound badge tags on Meta? (i.e. let's group [epic] and [legendary])](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50774/289691)
  - [How should "compound" tags be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93607/289691)
  - ["[open]" + "[source]" versus "[open-source]"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127672/289691) (the answer uses the referred term)
  - [What are the Technical and Usability Limitations of the Tag System?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297896/289691) (the answer uses the referred term)
  - [Compound tags: Do we need them?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2939) (from Islam Meta)
  - [Is the [date] tag useful?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2679/88163) (from Web Applications, the answer uses the referred term)
  - [Should an ORACLE-SPATIAL tag be created?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786) (from DBA Meta, the answer uses the referred term)
- Superset-tag ->   [Tag policy: include superset tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113931/289691)
- Hyphenated tag ->

  - [When should I create a hyphenated tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133410/289691)
  - [A new hyphenated tag can be created when an unhyphenated version exists as a synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183356/289691)
  - [A new unhyphenated tag can be created when a hyphenated version exists as a synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210994/289691)
  - [How to split hyphenated tag-strings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229359/289691)
- Composite tag ->

  - [Why can you put a single + in the tags field?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7229/289691)
  - [How to deal with redundant composite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139509/289691)
  - [Query about the tag to use for Questions on SSIS Data Flow tasks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284820/1595451) (from SO, one of the answers use the referred term)
- Hybrid tag ->     [We should NOT have hybrid tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190540/289691)
- Overloaded tag ->

  - [scribe is an overloaded tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95863/289691)
  - [Someone overloaded tag; how should we "unload"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288097/1595451) (from SO Meta)
  - [Proposal to remove tags like brick-wall and road-block](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/81) (from Genealogy & Family History, one of the answers use the referred term)

Commonly used

- Combination tags

  - [Combination tag wiki pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73053/289691)
  - [Email subscription to a combination of tags (using AND operator)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78107/289691)
  - [Watch combination tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322704/289691)
- Redundant tags

  - [Please remove some redundant tags from the list of default tags on child metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234473/289691)

"Marvelous" terms

- Redundant composite tag -> [How to deal with redundant composite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139509/289691)

Related

- [How are new users expected to learn about the "tag philosophy" of each SE site, and how to tag properly on that site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220029/289691)

Comment: I wouldn't say any of those have "accepted" meanings by anyone. People just sometimes use whatever adjective they feel best describes the situation in the heat of the moment. An official glossary is meant to include terms that you commonly see throughout the UI, that are a part of the site. Including every weird phrase that someone coins in casual discussion makes a glossary bloated and worthless. Those phrases are not actually used anywhere in the UI and thus most people would not know to even search for them, and might generate their own, different adjective in their head.

Comment: @animuson That includes "blocked/blacklisted" tag?

Comment: I understand the sentiment, but keeping such a thing complete,  up-to-date *and* organized for the next 10 years is going to be an awful lot of work, if not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> how to proceed when a new meaning arises for a term that has an accepted meaning between SE tag experts but might not be so obvious for others.

post a comment to the question to help the OP to learn the SE jargon, if there is a question about the related term / meaning, include a link to it.

Regarding creating a FAQ style question for tag related terms only do this is when it's really needed, like, when there is a term used in the UI that requires clarification and / or guidance. In these cases use [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology) not [glossary](/questions/tagged/glossary).

Related

- [Make [glossary] a synonym of [terminology]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353449/289691)